# 〜など in 病気になった人など

Tags: grammar

My grammar reference says that 〜など serves to "present a few examples out of a larger range of items". But what larger range of items is being referred to in this context? Isn't "those who have become sick" the only category being analyzed, not merely part of a larger category?

> 1月15日と16日に「大学入学共通テスト」があります。53万人ぐらいが受ける予定です。このテストと大学が行う試験で合格を決める大学と、このテストだけで決める大学があります。**病気になった人など**のために、29日と30日にも試験があります。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possible situations and emergencies that will render a student unable to attend the exams, should they find themself in one, and getting sick is just one of them. Getting hit by a car, train/bus/plane/boat delays, <strike>oversleeping</strike> (oversleeping is unacceptable, so exam-takers should remember to carefully set alarms), and getting beamed up by a UFO and abducted by aliens are other possibilities. That's why this is an inexhaustive list of the reasons why a student is not able to attend the exams on the 15th and 16th, and to provide for such unforeseeable accidents, another set of exams are scheduled on the 29th and 30th.

Comment: +1, but oversleeping is not an acceptable reason for the 追試験 :)